# How to set up encoding for Redis Sentinel?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I try to use Redis Sentinel as a cache to store some strings in Cyrillic symbols,
but when I retrieve these strings from Redis I receive '?????' symbols instead of Cyrillic symbols.

How to configure Redis to store/retrieve Cyrillic symbols correctly?

I work with Redis from Spring Boot application.

Comment: Do you mind adding some code snippet? Redis is storing binary content and does not apply any transformation.  Do you use SpringData Redis? Cache Manager? (I would like to do some testing to help you)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a serializer for RedisTemplate. Use something like this

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

  @Bean
  public <T> RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, T> template = new RedisTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
  }

}
```